# Choosing Between Monetary Compensation or Last Authorship in a Research Project Outside My Field

Tags: publications, research-process, career-path, authorship, interdisciplinary

I have recently been presented with an opportunity to contribute to a research project by creating a dataset, a task that would take approximately 100 hours of work. The project is not directly related to my field of study or research interests. I am faced with a choice: I can either receive monetary compensation for my work or be credited as the last author on any resulting publications.

Given that the project is outside my area of expertise, I am uncertain about the best course of action. On the one hand, being an author could diversify my academic portfolio, but on the other hand, the monetary compensation is also appealing.

How should I weigh the benefits of authorship in a field not aligned with my own against the immediate benefits of financial compensation?

Comment: Probably too personal for an answer here. Talk to people who know you with whom you can discuss your goals. Money is good. Recognition is good. Your call.

Comment: That really should not be an either/or proposition. Either the intellectual effort suffices for authorship or it doesn't. Payment is entirely separate.

Answer (score 16):

This is an unethical proposition. Authorship should not be sold for money; that's effectively the proposal here. Either you're selling away your rights to be an author, or you are purchasing authorship, depending on how you look at it.

If the work is an intellectual contribution you must be an author. If the work is work, you should be paid for it. Depending on where the work is done, it may be legally mandated that you are paid for work.

Comment: I agree with this and upvoted, though I suspect confronting the group on this will lead to getting neither the authorship nor the money.

Comment: @Dave In that case they didn't really need OP for anything; if they need OP for something, they'll get both. Better not to work with people who behave this way, it's certain for there to be "another shoe to drop" somewhere along the line.

Answer (score 0):

What they are offering you is the basic deal offered to scores of undergraduate and graduate students every year: you can get compensated with money (e.g. and RA) or you can get authorship. Yes, there is no reason why they can't both pay you and give you credit, but in the spirit of exploitation, it's the way it goes. From your description, it does not seem that they are asking you to come up with ideas or contribute to the writing, but to do technical work. Seems similar to doing lab work, and in my field, it's very common to offer the choice of money or authorship. (Note: I am very against this practice, and have always offered both money and authorship. But my experience/practice does not make it the rule.)

When I was a young grad student and presented this choice, I always took the money, and I still feel it was the right choice. I used the money to buy equipment and pay for trips to conferences. Oh, and groceries, which were very helpful in writing my own papers.

Comment: No, this is not a basic deal offered to scores of students; the "or" should not be there, "and" is there instead, when you have a functional university/research group. I'm sorry you've been treated this way but it is not normal.

Comment: I agree with Bryan, this is very unusual. You can get credit *or* paid in most places, but authorship is orthogonal. And on top of that you used the money you got paid to buy equipment and pay for conferences??